Compiling v8 on external SSD drive unexpectedly fails with strange errors
I am trying to compile v8 on Windows 11, having VisualStudio 2022 Community Edition. Googling and stackoverflowing didn't help me so far. I follow the steps like like described in v8 docs source code.
First I download and update depot_tools, on external SSD drive. After I unpack depot_tools and run gclient I get following, which is not expected according to documentation:
D:\compile\google\depot_tools>gclient
Updating depot_tools...
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Downloading CIPD client for windows-amd64 from https://chrome-infra-packages.appspot.com/client?platform=windows-amd64&version=git_revision:b1f414539ac10cc67a0250890a38712cc06cf102...
error: could not write config file D:/compile/google/depot_tools/bootstrap-2@3_11_8_chromium_35_bin/git/etc/gitconfig: File exists
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\compile\google\depot_tools\bootstrap\bootstrap.py", line 347, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\compile\google\depot_tools\bootstrap\bootstrap.py", line 319, in main
    git_postprocess(template, os.path.join(bootstrap_dir, 'git'))
  File "D:\compile\google\depot_tools\bootstrap\bootstrap.py", line 292, in git_postprocess
    call_if_outdated(os.path.join(git_directory, '.git_postprocess'),
  File "D:\compile\google\depot_tools\bootstrap\bootstrap.py", line 139, in call_if_outdated
    fn()
  File "D:\compile\google\depot_tools\bootstrap\bootstrap.py", line 281, in configure_git_system
    _check_call(
  File "D:\compile\google\depot_tools\bootstrap\bootstrap.py", line 196, in _check_call
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(proc.returncode, argv, None)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['D:\\compile\\google\\depot_tools\\git.bat', 'config', '--system', 'core.autocrlf', 'false']' returned non-zero exit status 4.

I removed D:/compile/google/depot_tools/bootstrap-2@3_11_8_chromium_35_bin/git/etc/gitconfig and ran gclient once again, apparently successful, but only apparently, never know. But the fetch v8 fails anyway.
While doing the fetch step I get following error
Error: Command '%ProgramFiles%\\Git\\mingw64\\bin\\git.exe -c color.ui=never config --local --replace-all remote.origin.fetch +refs/branch-heads/*:refs/remotes/branch-heads/* ^\\+refs/branch-heads/\\*:.*$' returned non-zero exit status 128 in D:\compile\google\v8
fatal: --local can only be used inside a git repository

The D: drive is an external SSD Drive, but I don't expect this to cause any problem. In the past I've succeeded to compile on external HDD drives as well as on internal HDD.
Here is the initial folder structure
D:\compile\google\  
D:\compile\google\depot_tools

And the initial environment setup
>set
...
Path=%ProgramFiles%\Git\usr\bin;%ProgramFiles%\Git\mingw64\bin;%ProgramFiles%\Git\cmd;D:\compile\google\depot_tools;......
vs2022_install=%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
...
8>git config --list --global
user.name=MyAndMyself
user.email=MeAndMyself@gmail.com
safe.directory=D:/compile/google/depot_tools
safe.directory=D:/compile/google/chromium/src
safe.directory=D:/compile/google/v8
safe.directory=D:/compile/google/v8/v8
core.longpaths=true
core.autocrlf=false
core.filemode=false
branch.autosetuprebase=always

Then I do following, as described in above documentation
cd /D D:\compile\google\
mkdir v8
cd v8

The fetch does different things, and also adds one new directory D:\compile\google\v8\v8
D:\compile\google\v8>fetch v8
Updating depot_tools...
Running: '%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\.vpython-root\store\python_venv-i6tr2130veudc7mkhurk6h3cao\contents\Scripts\python3.exe' 'D:\compile\google\depot_tools\gclient.py' root
Running: '%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\.vpython-root\store\python_venv-i6tr2130veudc7mkhurk6h3cao\contents\Scripts\python3.exe' 'D:\compile\google\depot_tools\gclient.py' config --spec 'solutions = [
  {
    "name": "v8",
    "url": "https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git",
    "deps_file": "DEPS",
    "managed": False,
    "custom_deps": {},
  },
]
'
Running: '%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\.vpython-root\store\python_venv-i6tr2130veudc7mkhurk6h3cao\contents\Scripts\python3.exe' 'D:\compile\google\depot_tools\gclient.py' sync --with_branch_heads

________ running 'git -c core.deltaBaseCacheLimit=2g clone --no-checkout --progress https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git D:\compile\google\v8\_gclient_v8_kyoywjwd' in 'D:\compile\google\v8'
Cloning into 'D:\compile\google\v8\_gclient_v8_kyoywjwd'...
remote: Total 1136232 (delta 918600), reused 1136232 (delta 918600)
Receiving objects: 100% (1136232/1136232), 1.43 GiB | 19.36 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (918600/918600), done.

________ running 'git -c core.deltaBaseCacheLimit=2g clone --no-checkout --progress https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git D:\compile\google\v8\_gclient_v8__cglk3b5' in 'D:\compile\google\v8'
Cloning into 'D:\compile\google\v8\_gclient_v8__cglk3b5'...
remote: Total 1136232 (delta 918600), reused 1136232 (delta 918600)
Receiving objects: 100% (1136232/1136232), 1.43 GiB | 19.61 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (918600/918600), done.
Syncing projects: 100% ( 1/ 1) v8
v8 (ERROR)
----------------------------------------
[0:00:00] Started.
[0:00:01]
[0:03:50] _____ Conflicting directory found in D:\compile\google\v8\v8. Moving to D:\compile\google\v8\_bad_scm\v8clftymnp.
[0:03:50]
----------------------------------------
Error: Command '%ProgramFiles%\\Git\\mingw64\\bin\\git.exe -c color.ui=never config --local --replace-all remote.origin.fetch +refs/branch-heads/*:refs/remotes/branch-heads/* ^\\+refs/branch-heads/\\*:.*$' returned non-zero exit status 128 in D:\compile\google\v8
fatal: --local can only be used inside a git repository



Warnings:
Conflicting directory D:\compile\google\v8\v8 moved to D:\compile\google\v8\_bad_scm\v8clftymnp.

Subprocess failed with return code 1.

D:\compile\google\v8>


Problem solved.

depot_tools will not work correctly on external SSD drive, but work on internal SSD. I would not expect this when following b8 build documentation.
fetch v8 and compile can be done on external SSD drive.

Compilation was incredibly quick. It took less than 60 minutes for x64.release and like 80 minutes for x64.debug. Comparing to previous laptop, compilation on the internal HDD, the x64.release took considerable more than 24 hours, where I didn't dare even to think about x64.debug.
The Environment: Win11 x64, VisualStudio 2022, SanDisk Extreme PRO Portable SSD 1TB.

First step, followed as steps to install depot_tools as described in  according to b8 build documentation, but on internal SSD, and all it was successful, got this output:

Second step, fetch v8 I did on external SSD. And it succeeded.
D:\compile\google>md v8

D:\compile\google>cd v8

D:\compile\google\v8>fetch v8
Updating depot_tools...
Running: '%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\.vpython-root\store\python_venv-i6tr2130veudc7mkhurk6h3cao\contents\Scripts\python3.exe' 'C:\DiskD\programe\source\depot_tools\gclient.py' root
Running: '%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\.vpython-root\store\python_venv-i6tr2130veudc7mkhurk6h3cao\contents\Scripts\python3.exe' 'C:\DiskD\programe\source\depot_tools\gclient.py' config --spec 'solutions = [
  {
    "name": "v8",
    "url": "https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git",
    "deps_file": "DEPS",
    "managed": False,
    "custom_deps": {},
  },
]
'
Running: '%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\.vpython-root\store\python_venv-i6tr2130veudc7mkhurk6h3cao\contents\Scripts\python3.exe' 'C:\DiskD\programe\source\depot_tools\gclient.py' sync --with_branch_heads

________ running 'git -c core.deltaBaseCacheLimit=2g clone --no-checkout --progress https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git D:\compile\google\v8\_gclient_v8_ebld6x4n' in 'D:\compile\google\v8'
Cloning into 'D:\compile\google\v8\_gclient_v8_ebld6x4n'...
remote: Finding sources: 100% (60/60)           ng objects: 1
remote: Total 1137789 (delta 919626), reused 1137767 (delta 919626)
Receiving objects: 100% (1137789/1137789), 1.44 GiB | 20.19 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (919626/919626), done.

[0:02:40] Still working on:
[0:02:40]   v8

[0:02:50] Still working on:
[0:02:50]   v8

[0:03:00] Still working on:
[0:03:00]   v8

[0:03:10] Still working on:
[0:03:10]   v8
1>Syncing projects:   0% ( 0/ 2)
[0:03:19] Still working on:
[0:03:19]   v8

[0:03:19] Still working on:
[0:03:19]   v8
Syncing projects: 100% (39/39), done.

________ running 'python3 third_party/depot_tools/download_from_google_storage.py --no_resume --no_auth -u --bucket v8-wasm-spec-tests -s test/wasm-spec-tests/tests.tar.gz.sha1' in 'D:\compile\google\v8\v8'
0> Downloading test/wasm-spec-tests/tests.tar.gz@ca113d061aedcf62fd53761337efc73e17fcc5bd...
0> Extracting 1064 entries from test/wasm-spec-tests/tests.tar.gz to test/wasm-spec-tests/tests
Downloading 1 files took 56.756558 second(s)
Hook 'python3 third_party/depot_tools/download_from_google_storage.py --no_resume --no_auth -u --bucket v8-wasm-spec-tests -s test/wasm-spec-tests/tests.tar.gz.sha1' took 57.00 secs
Running hooks:  39% ( 9/23) wasm_js
________ running 'python3 third_party/depot_tools/download_from_google_storage.py --no_resume --no_auth -u --bucket v8-wasm-spec-tests -s test/wasm-js/tests.tar.gz.sha1' in 'D:\compile\google\v8\v8'
0> Downloading test/wasm-js/tests.tar.gz@bd895cf2be978dd981234ba213e594cf09bfe7a6...
0> Extracting 310 entries from test/wasm-js/tests.tar.gz to test/wasm-js/tests
Downloading 1 files took 6.226099 second(s)
Hook 'vpython3.bat -vpython-spec .vpython3 -vpython-tool install' took 15.53 secs
Running hooks:  95% (22/23) configure_reclient_cfgs
________ running 'python3 buildtools/reclient_cfgs/configure_reclient_cfgs.py --rbe_instance projects/rbe-chrome-untrusted/instances/default_instance --reproxy_cfg_template reproxy.cfg.template --rewrapper_cfg_project  --skip_remoteexec_cfg_fetch' in 'D:\compile\google\v8\v8'
generate reproxy.cfg using D:\compile\google\v8\v8\buildtools\reclient_cfgs\reproxy_cfg_templates\reproxy.cfg.template
Running hooks: 100% (23/23), done.
Running: git config --add remote.origin.fetch '+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*'
Running: git config diff.ignoreSubmodules dirty

At least, the first preparation step is done with no errors.
Now compiled, tools/dev/gm.py x64.release is ran on external SSD with no aberrations. Yeah, on windows it has to be tools\dev\gm.py x64.release. Or like I did python3 tools\dev\gm.py x64.release, because I keep my system as clean as possible.
The question was asked also here.

I agree that this is unexpected. FWIW, I doubt that drives being internal or external has anything to do with it; instead I'd guess that unintentionally some assumption has snuck in that the depot_tools directory is somewhere on C:\ (but that does sound weird too, usually a path is a path and the drive doesn't matter). If you care enough, you could try to debug it :-)
